# How do I point a BitBake recipe to a local file / Yocto build fails to fetch sources for libtalloc

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build Yocto for Raspberry Pi3, with console-image, and it gives me some build errors, most I have been able to resolve with

```
bitbake -c cleansstate libname
bitbake libname
```

However, now it got to libtalloc and it can't do_fetch the source files.

I went to the URL of the sources, and I was able to download the exact tar.gz archive it was trying to fetch. i.e. http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz

I even put it into /build/downloads folder.

But when I try to bitbake, it keeps giving me the same errors

Is there a way I can configure the build process to always fetch with http or wget, it seems that the these scripts are all broken, because it cant fetch a file that exists.

Thanks,

Here is the full printout:

```
WARNING: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-ATqIt180d4"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring-Ubo22d/ssh"; export PATH="/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/python-native:/home/dmitry/poky-morty/scripts:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi2/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/sbin:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/sbin:/home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/bin:/home/dmitry/poky-morty/scripts:/home/dmitry/poky-morty/bitbake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"; export HOME="/home/dmitry"; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 -nv --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /home/dmitry/rpi/build/downloads 'http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 4, output:
--2017-01-24 12:35:19--  http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz
Resolving samba.org (samba.org)... 144.76.82.156, 2a01:4f8:192:486::443:2
Connecting to samba.org (samba.org)|144.76.82.156|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2017-01-24 12:35:20--  (try: 2)  http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz
Connecting to samba.org (samba.org)|144.76.82.156|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Giving up.


ERROR: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/dmitry/rpi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libtalloc/2.1.8-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.80102
ERROR: Task (/home/dmitry/poky-morty/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/libtalloc/libtalloc_2.1.8.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

Comment: you can download the code manually and set it as a mirror to the recipe's URL

Comment: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/How_do_I#Q:_How_do_I_create_my_own_source_download_mirror_.3F

Comment: I followe the instructions, and I added  to local.conf        SOURCE_MIRROR_URL ?= "file://home/rpi/build/sources/"
 INHERIT += "own-mirrors" 
 BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS = "1"                and I placed the tarball into /home/rpi/build/sources    It still gives me the same error. This time it took a little longer

Comment: When I added the BB_NO_NETWORK = "1" Flag I get a different error:    ERROR: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Network access disabled through BB_NO_NETWORK (or set indirectly due to use of BB_FETCH_PREMIRRORONLY) but access requested with command /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 -nv --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /home/user/rpi/build/downloads 'http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz' (for url None)
ERROR: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch

Comment: ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/rpi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/libtalloc/2.1.8-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.81312
ERROR: Task (/home/user/poky-morty/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/libtalloc/libtalloc_2.1.8.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can configure the build process to always fetch with http or wget, it seems that the these scripts are all broken, because it cant fetch a file that exists.

The scripts already use both wget and http. They're also not really broken, the people maintaining the samba download servers just changed several things in the past week: I believe the libtalloc recipes main SRC_URI just needs to be changed to `https://download.samba.org/pub/talloc/talloc-${PV}.tar.gz` (the current canonical samba download server).

I'm sure meta-oe maintainer would appreciate a patch if this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the following patch to meta-openembedded and got it built. There are several samba links already broken.

http://pastebin.com/0uTnAY4g

Regards,
M.